# Serialization using GZipStream

Tags: c#, serialization

I keep getting this recursive error when using my plugin. Because it is an addon to something written in mono I can't see the full stack trace, just the text version. I'm trying to serialize a GZipStream from a MemoryStream to a object and back. My code:

```
    public byte[] Bytes
    {
        set
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(value, 0, value.Length);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (var gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    Value = (T)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(gzip);
                    gzip.Close();
                }
                ms.Close();
            }
            valChanged = true;
        }
        get
        {
            if (!valChanged) return bytes;
            if (Value == null) return null;
            if (!Value.GetType().IsSerializable) return null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(gzip, Value);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            valChanged = false;
            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

The exception I get when executing this and serializing is `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.` I've tried `ms.Position = 0;` and `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` but they both have the same output. I've looked at a bunch of other Stackoverflow questions about this but they don't seem to help.

Comment: P.S. it's on the Bytes.set, Bytes.get isn't really that important

Comment: I'd try the `bytes = ms.ToArray()` part outside of the first using, if I were you.

Comment: I actually did try that it didn't solve anything.

Comment: You cannot call `ToArray()` on the `MemoryStream` object until you have closed the `GZipStream`, otherwise the gzip data isn't complete. See marked duplicate.

Comment: no, this is on the `Bytes.set`. The `Bytes.get` is working just fine. I just need help on the deserialization because the serialization it working just fine.